# How should InputFormat be coded when dealing with custom file format?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Although this is a more generic question I can't find much detailed help on the particular situation here. I have a large number of files of large size (each on average 2GB). These files contain entries that are coded in a custom format which must be read by another library to resolve into individual entries. Now I wish to use MapReduce to parse these files, but the default InputFormat and InputSplit processes files line by line, which is not what I want. It seems that I have to specify how to split the files (each split should contain some number of entries) and how to generate records (each entry should map to a key/value> pair).

What methods should I override in order to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the custom format?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile

Comment: The problem lies in that I do not know exactly how are the files formatted; I can only rely on an external library to parse them.

Comment: Do you need the whole 2GB file to be processed by a single mapper?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input file format (the response you gave to @rath was a link to hadoop documentation about Sequence files)

Comment: @ChrisWhite That wasn't me (wink Since the input file is composed of "entries" it should be better to enable splitting the file. But of course having each mapper processing a single file is one solution, just not that good at load balancing.

Comment: Sorry, string matched the first letter of the username.., but still - example file contents?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by writing a Custom InputFormat for this input file
1. You should set what will be the start and end of a split
   1.1 You can set what is the start of a line and end of line
2. A Record reader for this split to read the records inside the split.

The below is an example for reading XML. This should get you started.
[XML File Processing](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/integration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/text/wikipedia/XmlInputFormat.java)